# Посчитать сумму модулей элементов массива расположенных после первого отрицательного элемента

Tags: python

В моём коде не получается посчитать сумму модулей элементов массива после первого отрицательного числа, так как знак минус не поддерживается для типа `int`. Причём я сделал модуль числа, но всё равно работает некорректно:

```
arr = input("Введите список:")
print(arr.split(' '))
arr = list(arr)
N = len(arr)
neg = -1
s = 0
d = 0
neg = -1
for i in range(N):
    if arr[i] < '0':
        neg = i
        break

if neg == -1:
    print('Отрицательных нет')
else:
    print('Номер первого отриц.:', neg+1)
    for i in range(neg+1,N):
        d = arr.pop(1)
        d = int(d)
        d = abs(d)
        s += d 

    print('Сумма: ', s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение без явных циклов:

```
arr = list(map(int, input("Введите список: ").split()))

try:
    first_neg_pos = arr.index(next(filter(lambda x: x < 0, arr)))
    print('Номер первого отриц.:', first_neg_pos+1)
    res = sum(abs(x) for x in arr[first_neg_pos+1:])
    print('Сумма: ', res)
except StopIteration:
    #first_neg_pos = -1
    print('Отрицательных нет')
```

пример ввода:

```
Введите список: 1 2 -1 4 -12 10 -3
```

результат:

```
Номер первого отриц.: 3
Сумма:  29
```

---

Ошибка (логическая) в строке:

```
d = arr.pop(1)
```

вместо вашего кода используйте:

```
arr = list(map(int, input("Введите список: ").split()))

s = 0
neg = -1
for i,n in enumerate(arr):
    if n < 0:
        neg = i
        break

for n in arr[neg+1:]:
    s += abs(n)
```

Comment: я вам благодарен ,но хотелось бы узнать,что мне исправить в моём коде?

Comment: а разве в конце я это не сделал?

Comment: @Noob_Prog, да, не дочитал весь ответ до конца... ;)

Comment: то что вы предложили не работает в программе s += abs(int(arr[i]))

Comment: @Noob_Prog, у меня работает ;)

Comment: пожалуйста выложите мой код с вашими изменениями возможно я не правильно у себя исправил

Comment: @Noob_Prog, мне ваш код не нравится, поэтому я лучше приведу код с циклами, но все таки по-своему...

Comment: то что вы предложили это по сути тоже самое,что было у меня единственное,что у вас не было это arr.pop(1)

Comment: first_neg_pos = arr.index(next(filter(lambda x: x < 0, arr)))
я правильно,понял,что лямбда создаёт и возвращает функцию,для которой икс меньше нуля, которая передаётся в функцию filter() которая возвращает те элементы последовательности для которых данная функция икс меньше нуля истинна которая передаётся в функцию next()

Comment: @Noob_Prog, да, вы правильно поняли

Comment: в случае не нахождения x< 0 возвращает следующий элемент последовательности,а в случае нахождения передается в index который возвращает положение первого такого элемента и сохраняется результат в переменной first_neg_pos

Comment: это всё что хотел у вас узнать

Comment: @Noob_Prog, в случае если отрицательные элементы отсутствуют - сработает исключение `StopIteration`, которое мы перехватываем и обрабатываем

Comment: Возник ещё вопрос,за счёт чего у нас вычисляется сумма модулей НЕ С ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНОГО ЭЛЕМЕНТА,а С ПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНОГО то есть получается,что у нас не включается отрицательный элемент за счёт чего?

Comment: @Noob_Prog, `first_neg_pos+1`

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста строчку где res присваивается сумма модулей чисел,что мы берём в качестве аргумента здесь и вообще что здесь пошагово выполняется

Comment: @Noob_Prog, если хотите понять как это работает пошагово, то возьмите эту конструкцию и запускайте ее по частям. Например: `print(arr[first_neg_pos+1:])`, `print([abs(x) for x in arr[first_neg_pos+1:]])`, `print(sum(abs(x) for x in arr[first_neg_pos+1:]))`...

Answer (score 2):

Аналогичное @MaxU, более декларативно.

```
from itertools import dropwhile

a = [1, 2, -1, 4, -12, 10, -3]
after = dropwhile(lambda x: x>=0, a)
try:
    next(after) # пропускаем сам отрицательный элемент
    print(sum(map(abs, after))) # -> 29
except StopIteration:
    print('Отрицательных нет')
```

Comment: красивое использование `dropwhile` +1

Comment: мне не нужно решение без функции ввода,но за решение всё равно спасибо

Comment: @Noob_Prog А разве функция ввода вызывает затруднения? Если да, можете ее взять из ответа MaxU.

Comment: @Lecron, а как на счет вывода индекса первого отрицательного элемента?

Comment: @MaxU Условие задачи: сумма модулей после. А в коде встречаются ошибки)). Вообще считаю, если в решении участвуют индексы элементов, значит с ним скорее всего что-то не так. Конечно кроме случаев, когда он прямо требуется по техзаданию.

Comment: как правило `map` работает медленнее списочніх віражений. Да и менее понятный текст.  Так что `sum(map(abs, after))` понятнее выглядит как  `sum([abs(x) for x in after])`

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Предварительная оптимизация — зло! Тем более, что в данном случае, %timeit говорит, что map 1.46ms, а comprehension 1.72ms. На счет понятности, тоже не понятно)) Когда нужно вставлять лямбду, списки выигрывают, но если можно обойтись короткой функцией, выигрывает map, за счет меньшего количества boilerplate кода.